# Download content from URI and modify it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I got list of URI links for example `http://news.yahoo.com`  ,  `http://www.google.com`

I want to download the content from those links and modify the data / change the css names in the page.

Comment: You want to do this in JavaScript?  You can't.  JavaScript can't just load arbitrary URLs.  You need to have a server-side script download the URLs, then send them to your page.

Answer (score 1):

Without a server-side component doing the downloading for you, this ain't going to work. With a server-side component you can just use `.load()` of course.

You might find a solution here: http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide